# Logstash sincedb file not being created

Tags: logstash

This is my logstash config file:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "SystemError"
        path => "/path/to/file/systemerr/**/*"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/data/sincedb"

        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\s"
            what => "previous"
        }      
    }
}
```

I have even tried not entering sincedb_path at all and using default path

```
input {
    file {
        type => "SystemError"
        path => "/path/to/file/systemerr/**/*"
        start_position => "beginning"

        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\s"
            what => "previous"
        }      
    }
}
```

But even that is not working. My user has rights to the folder that the sincedb file should be written into. I also tried as root user. But nothing is working.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you three suggestions:

1. instead of **  try a single *
2. write the extension of the files in the folder. I am sure they are of the same extension for ex. if all your files are in csv format you can write  */*.csv
3. If you are working on a windows machine use backslash please